# Получить результат выполнения C функции из исполняемого файла, у которого отсутствуют необходимые зависимости

Tags: python, c++, linux, gcc

У меня есть LSB pie executable файл. Согласно [этой](https://lief-project.github.io//doc/latest/tutorials/08_elf_bin2lib.html) статье у меня получается вызывать функцию, название которой я знаю.

```
import lief
import ctypes

app = lief.parse("./executable")
addr = app.get_function_address("getInfo")
print(addr)
app.add_exported_function(addr, "getInfo")
app[lief.ELF.DYNAMIC_TAGS.FLAGS_1].remove(lief.ELF.DYNAMIC_FLAGS_1.PIE)
app.write("./temp.so")

tempLib = ctypes.CDLL("./temp.so")
tempLib.getInfo.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
print(tempLib.getInfo())
```

С этим проблем нет, все работает.
Однако, если у executable есть отсутствующие зависимости, мы не сможем выполнить

```
tempLib = ctypes.CDLL("./temp.so")
```

Собственно в этом и вопрос. Возможно ли как-то выполнить и получить результат функции, определенной в executable и адресс которой мы знаем, несмотря на отсутствующие зависимости? Либо, возможно ли скопировать ее в другой исполняемый/разделяемый файл, где уже не будет проблем ее выполнить?
Разумеется, сама функция не использует никакие объекты, а только возвращает значение макроса, определяемого при сборке.
Примерно:

```
extern "C" const char* getInfo() { return INFO; }
```

Заранее извиняюсь, если эти вопросы откровенно глупые. В теме слаб.

Comment: Если функция "только возвращает значение макроса, определяемого при сборке", то у полученной из нее библиотеки не будет внешних зависемостей.

Comment: Самое простое, что можно сделать - проанализировать зависимости, и написать *.so - заглушку, в которой нужные символы будут определены.

Comment: @user7860670 Я не говорил, что executable состоит из одной этой функции. Там может быть любой функционал и любые подключаемые библиотеки, для меня это не имеет значение. Для меня важно, что я точно знаю, что там будет некая функция, имя и сигнатуру которой я знаю, а значит могу получить адресс и вызвать, что я и делаю в примере.

Comment: Тогда без зависимостей запустить не получится. В теории можно написать свой загрузчик и запускать что-то, наплевав на зависимости, но целесообразность таких действий вызывает сомнения. Если хочется просто получить доступ к строке, то имеет смысл добавлять ее как ресурс, без кода.

Comment: В том то и дело, что меня не интересует все остальное, кроме нужных мне функций. Меня устроит, например, вариант "слепить" новый бинарник, либо удалить все ненужное в текущем. Просто я не совсем понимаю, что вообще возможно, а что нет, и в какую сторону лучше копать.